# Using proxy or shortcuts methods in PHP

Tags: php, methods

I have classes with larges methods name that are called too many times.

Example:

```
/**
 * This class do awesome things.
 */
class AwesomeClass {

    /**
     * Do something awesome.
     */
    public function doSomethingAwesome()
    {
        //Do something awesome
    }
}
```

Now, I call the method:

```
$awesomeInstance->doSomethingAwesome();
```

The method name is large and is typed to many times. For prevent misspelling, I created a shortcut method:

```
/**
 * Shortcut of doSomethingAwesome()
 */
public function dsa()
{
    return $this->doSomethingAwesome();
}
```

And calling method:

```
$awesomeInstance->dsa();
```

Is this a bad practice? How afect the performance?

Comment: i suggest to use any IDE like `netbeans` which will give you options that which function you call, in that case you dont need functions like this and there will be no more spelling errors. This is not a good practice lets say if you 100 functions than you have to define 100 shortcut functions like this.

Comment: Sounds like a delegate design pattern

Comment: Delegate pattern is used to provide code reuse. In this case it's code duplication for the sake of shorter method names.

Comment: @SahilGulati I use PHPStorm IDE, and I don't have misspelling problems, the answer is is general. For the other hand, I use this shortcut method for avoid too long lines.

Answer (score 2):

It is a commonly stated rule of thumb that **code is read more often than it is written**. Even if writing code only for your own use, you will not remember everything about how it works when you read it back in 6 months time to make some amendment.

Your shortcut method names *optimise your codebase for writing*, because they make it quicker to type, and less error-prone.

However, they are actively *harmful for reading*, because they lead to less descriptive code, and require you to cross-reference the comment on the shortcut to check what it abbreviates.

Instead, you should aim to write *the same code* (thus retaining readability) but find tools to do so *more easily and with fewer errors*. A major helper in this case would be using a more powerful code editor or IDE, which will include auto-complete and code navigation facilities. You can also use standalone "code linting" / "static analysis" tools to pick up mistyped function names.

Answer (score 0):

Performance shouldn't be an issue. But readability of your code suffers. You should use descriptive method names. If this function is called too many times it's a code smell and some refactoring may be needed.

Comment: "You should use descriptive method names", he gave an example

Comment: So you think dsa is more descriptive than doSomethingAwesome or you're just nitpicking?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend creating shortcut methods. I am not sure why your methods do have such long names. Maybe your methods do more than one task?

for example:

```
$awesomeInstance->parseCheckAndSaveMyAwsomeObject();
```

in that case, you should write a dedicated method for each task.

Could you explain it in more detail?